# Creating a SWIG typemap for C++ overloaded functions

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I would like to know how to create a SWIG typemap for overloaded functions.

**MyBindings.h**

```
static void test(t_string *s)
{
    std::cout << "first : " << s->name << '\n');
}

static void test(t_string *s, t_string *s2)
{
    std::cout << "first : " << s->name << '\n');
    std::cout << "second : " << s2->name << '\n');
}
```

**MyBindings.i**

```
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include <stl.i>
%include <exception.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
/* convert the input lua_String to t_string* */
%typemap(in) t_string*
{
    if (!lua_isstring(L, $input))
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: string expected");
    $1 = makestring(lua_tostring(L, $input));
}
```

And if I call `test()` in Lua,

```
my.test("abc", "def");
```

I get the following error:

```
Wrong arguments for overloaded function 'test'
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    test(t_string *)
    test(t_string *,t_string *)
```

How should I correct my typemap to make it work?

Comment: shouldnt the arguments to test be std::string or [const] char*? I thought the whole idea of SWIG was to avoid writing interface code for languages like LUA?

Comment: @RichardHodges Would it work if I replace `t_string` with `std::string`?

Comment: I think that's the whole point of SWIG - to automatically provide other-language interfaces to c++ objects.

Comment: Your example is quite incomplete and full of syntax errors.  -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case of RTFM.  See [11.5.2 "typecheck" typemap](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_nn27):

> If you define new "in" typemaps *and* your program uses overloaded methods, you should also define a collection of "typecheck" typemaps. More details about this follow in the [Typemaps and overloading](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Typemaps_overloading) section.

As always in your questions, include guards were missing in your header file.  I just made my own `t_string.h` because I have no idea where this comes from.  The functions `test` cannot be static because after all you want to refer to them from outside this translation unit which is not possible when they have [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

**`MyBindings.h`**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "t_string.h"

void test(t_string *s)
{
    std::cout << "first : " << s->name << '\n';
}

void test(t_string *s, t_string *s2)
{
    std::cout << "first : " << s->name << '\n';
    std::cout << "second : " << s2->name << '\n';
}
```

**`MyBindings.i`**

```
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

/* convert the input lua_String to t_string* */
%typemap(typecheck) t_string* {
    $1 = lua_isstring(L, $input);
}
%typemap(in) t_string* {
    $1 = makestring(lua_tostring(L, $input));
}
%typemap(freearg) t_string* {
    freestring($1);
}
%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local my = require("my")
my.test("abc", "def")
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -lua MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2 -shared -fPIC MyBindings_wrap.cxx -o my.so -llua5.2
$ lua5.2 test.lua
first : abc
second : def
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much and I'm sorry for my poor question.

Comment: @ZackLee If you remove the syntax errors, add the missing details to `MyBindings.i`, and add a link to the library which provides `t_string`, I can convert my downvote into an upvote.